# Await function when used as a function parameter does not get resolved before the function is run

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, sapui5, es6-promise

The following code work as expected using async/await:

```
try {
       let feedbacks = await feedbackService.get(this.feedBackOdataModel);
        this.feedBackJsonModel.setProperty('/Avaliacoes', feedbacks.results);


        } catch (error) {
            dialogService.showErrorDialog("Erro na obtenção das pesquisas de satisfação", error.statusText + '-' + error.statusCode);
            throw new Error(error);
        }
```

The execution is halted until feedbackService gets resolved.

But this:

```
... 
this.feedBackJsonModel.setProperty('/Avaliacoes', await
     feedbackService.get(this.feedBackOdataModel).results); 
...
```

I imagine the result should be the same but it seens the the promise gets resolved after the setProperty is run.

Comment: Have you tried `this.feedBackJsonModel.setProperty('/Avaliacoes', (await feedbackService.get(this.feedBackOdataModel)).results);`? Also, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: are you ***sure*** you're using that `await` inside a function that has been marked with the `async` keyword?? We can't tell from your code examples

Comment: @slebetman Using `await` inside a non-async function would be a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two code examples are not equivalent. In the first, you are awaiting

```
feedbackService.get(this.feedBackOdataModel)
```

which is presumably a promise, and in the second, you are awaiting

```
feedbackService.get(this.feedBackOdataModel).results
```

which is presumably `undefined`. So indeed, the `await` has essentially no effect, and `undefined` is passed into `setProperty` almost immediately.

To fix - use parentheses to correctly indicate what you are awaiting:

```
this.feedBackJsonModel.setProperty(
    '/Avaliacoes',
    (await feedbackService.get(this.feedBackOdataModel)).results
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering with what I put in a comment :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer!